# What are displacement vectors?

Tags: algorithm

I am clearly not the brightest spark in the fire when it comes to  algorithm design and as such am trying to understand what the following book exercise is asking me to do. Can somebody explain what the displacement is, given the question below? And maybe explain the re-world relevance of displacements?

> Say a vector P[1..m] occurs in a vector T[1..n] if P[1..m] =
>   T[s+1,..,s+m] for a value of "s". The value of this "s" is a valid
>   displacement. Develop an algorithm to find all the valid displacements
>   in a vector and analise it's complexity in relation to "m" and "n".

Comment: You can think of "displacement" as meaning the "the difference between two places". Here, `s` is the displacement from the beginning of the vector to the first element of `P` inside `T`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a fancy way of saying "`P` is a [substring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring) of `T` that occurs immediately after position `s`".

For example:

```
    012345678910
P = ra
T = abracadabra
      --     --
```

You'd have displacements at `s = 1` and `s = 8`, because `T[1+1, 1+2] = T[8+1,8+2] = ra`.

There are [many algorithms that can solve this problem](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/introduction-to-string-searching-algorithms/). A popular and good one is KMP.

Comment: Right, so `s` is a "displacement", or, in other words, an offset.